# How do I theme a block created with the Views module?

Tags: views, 7, theming

I'm Newbie user in drupal, i need to custom design theme block created for views module.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="content">
   <ul>
     <li>
        <div class="title">title1</div>
        <div class="thumbs"><img 1 ......></div>
        <div class="content">content1</div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <div class="title">title2</div>
        <div class="thumbs"><img 2 ......></div>
        <div class="content">content2</div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is your Drupal site already using a custom theme to which you can just add additional css to theme your block or are you asking how to add a custom theme in the first place?

Comment: i custom my theme using region/blocks. i start design theme/block with default views. i.e: `Front page` this print any content type with `promoted in front page` in index. this worked perfectly, now i need to custom this theme block for `my example html`. NOTE: i set (`Database overriding code`) field in views. now how to custom this block theme?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly sure what you are asking...

If you want to theme a view then you can add a css class name under the advanced drop-down, or add a  css class to any field.

Or are you looking to adjust how a block appears using views?

Comment: i.e: i need add custom theme for show last article in jquery news ticker.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to choose from.

1. Use the native template suggestion system that Drupal provides for you. Check template information when editing your view.
2. Use a contributed module like [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) which lets you customize the output of your view thoroughly from the back-end configuration.